# Asking user for photo, location, microphone and notification access without showing alert popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions

As far as I know and I did, when app asks user for access permissions, iOS will show alert popups and handle the result itself. My application needs up to 4 permissions which is not good to show 4 alerts to ask user for permissions. So my question is:

Instead of showing alert popups, is there any way to ask user for permissions similar to in Settings app? I would like to group all 4 permissions into a screen with titles and descriptions, each of them will come with a switch button, user turn switch on to give access like below:

Photo                 [on/off]
Notification          [on/off]
Location              [on/off]
Microphone            [on/off]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent iOS showing the alert popups.

I suggest you delay asking for permission until the user triggers an action that requires access - that way the user will find it less annoying.

Comment: Hi Nick, I remember I saw some apps that can ask for photos access by using a button instead of showing alert popup.